# Convertion overflowed an int column. Witouth convert() or cast()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having the structure:

[image]

In MGDCOCRE and MGDCODEB columns have similar values to '2158890000905' '2122190000905' ...

When trying to run a simple UPDATE or SELECT (E.G: select MGDIDENT from MGDMOCOT  where MGDIDPAG is not null and mgdcocre=1) in this table shows the error message:

> The conversion of the varchar value '2158890000397' overflowed an int column.

What is the possible solution of this problem?

Thank's

Comment: `and mgdcocre='1'` <- two ticks are the solution.

Comment: You need to post the query - something in the query is trying to implicitly convert the values to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
select MGDIDENT 
from MGDMOCOT 
where MGDIDPAG is not null and mgdcocre=1
```

What does SQL Server do here? Now, mgdcocre is varchar, but 1 is integer. So SQL Server implicitly casts all the varchars in `mgdcocre` column to integer to make an integer comparison against `1`. This fails because at least one of the varchars represents too big of a number for conversion to integer.

Solution:

```
select MGDIDENT 
from MGDMOCOT 
where MGDIDPAG is not null and mgdcocre='1'
```

Here you compare two varchars, so no cast is required.

Comment: Went unnoticed by my eyes. Thanks!